# Generic type with strict shape constraint in Typescript

Tags: typescript

When lookin at the following code:

```
type Test<T extends {a: number}> = ...doing something with keyof T...

Test<{a:1}> // ok
Test<{a:1, b:1}> // ok, but I want this to fail due to having 'b';
```

Is there any way to make the first one ok, but second one not ok by strictly limiting to the shape and not allowing extra properties.

Comment: `Test<{a: 1}>` is a weird thing to write, that's specifying a numeric literal type, not a value. If you want `Test`s to include *only* `a`, then you want `type Test = { a: number };`, surely? And then `const t: Test = { a: 1, b: 1 };` will be an error. You seem to be confusing generic types and values.

Comment: Not true. You don't know what Test is doing in '...'. It can do very complicated thing with `keyof T` and it's not same as `type Test = {a: number};`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `{a: 1}`. It extends `{a: number}` correctly. It can be useful type when you are creating a hashmap of some things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't to it directly, but you can ensure that the type will not really be usable if it has extra properties by using a conditional type:

```
type Test<T extends { a: number }> = Exclude<keyof T, keyof { a: number }> extends never ?  T : "T must be exactly of type { a: number }";
let ok: Test<{ a: number }> = { a: 10 }; // ok
let nok: Test<{ a: number, b: number }> = { a: 1, b: 2 }// nok; Type '{ a: number; b: number; }' is not assignable to type '"T must be exactly of type { a: number }"'.
```

**Further discussion**:

Typescript does check for extra properties on direct assignment of object literals, so this would be an error:

```
let a: { a: number } = { a: 1, b: 1 }; // error Object literal may only specify known properties...
```

But does allow assignment from other sources if the type is compatible (ie has more properties)

```
let ab = { a: 1, b: 1 };
let a: { a: number } = ab // ok
```

The above type (or variations of it) can help us create a function where we don't want excess properties and the generic parameter is inferred:

```
function create<T extends { a: number }>(p: T & (Exclude<keyof T, keyof { a: number }> extends never ?  T : "T must be exactly of type { a: number }")) : T{

}
create({ a: 1, b: 1 }); //Type '{ a: number; b: number; }' is not assignable to type '"T must be exactly of type { a: number }"'.
create({ a: 1 }); //ok
```

Comment: Thank you! this is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @Joon added more of a discussion, not sure how useful `Test` itself is, but the technique is applicable to functions where `T` is inferred.

Comment: Thank you so much! You've consistently been great help to me answering every question I have. I needed to restrict and not allow excessive property with my generic type alias and I have been having trouble, but now it's solved.

Comment: Instead of `Exclude<keyof T, keyof { a: number }> extends never ?  T : "T must be exactly of type { a: number }"` you may opt for a simpler `{ [K in Exclude<keyof {a: number} , keyof T>]: never }`.

Answer (score 1):

> but second one not ok by strictly limiting to the shape and not allowing extra properties.

Not with generics. Replace every T with its value e.g. replace `type Test<T extends {a: number}> = T` with `type Test = {a: number}`