# Typescript: how to create interface/type that has a nested object property with keys from this interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create interface/type that can limit his nested object property with only interface keys
Example:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
  prop1: string;
  promp2: number;
  nestedObj: {
    prop1: string; // Ok as MyClass has prop1 property 
    prop3: number; // Error as MyClass doesn't have prop3 property
  }
}
```

I try this but it doesn't work

```
export interface MyInterface {
  [key: string]: any;
  nestedObj: { [key2 in keyof Omit<MyInterface, 'nestedObj'>]: any };
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w2kZVN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Thank you. I want a generic solution. I don't want to repeat properties in interface and class.

Comment: What about [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUCwAoa0CWBbADiAKa5EB2ALhBllggJKVEBOAZmMEQDw21YDevPlnzMA9vgCMALmgQKzbGQDmAbiHDRYggCZZZAK64ARi3WZhAXwA0GrAHIyReUQAmAeWMArexoB8GIIWWlIAhLLyiirmIuK64dCGJma8Ti4e3glBfAD0OdAACuL4LBTw0PZauvY4MLjYUErKOGTQZSUV-NAhMnIKTardxQDM+kamzIOWNcYGFNDMRACOBtiLri1t8B32XT0R-dFD2vh6ieNm0NMa+31RajcjY8mTvJbmlhgYRAAe+GLMebtIhweCMCgsdicLgAFWs0AA0tBfhCyK4YEUJKV4AiiPA-NAALzQGHQABk0Gy0AA2gVNgiALqyGEfcxAA)?

Comment: Is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAKlAziAPHAfDAvPGAyGAb2BlJgDskQoATAeQCMArAfgC54q11gBfYUJFhxsRAB4dkAJwCW5AOYAaGGEkhZC5QC81G+bwDcAgMYB7cshgTOybqOJkrHAOQANZ4pJlVMZwE0PL1IdXwAtQMdKZFpGJg5CGAB6RJgAWRlERDl5Xy1nIMcnX3dPQu8XANKyfn5gMwsQFQ4EWwx7Aus3CPLfSoKQ53Cq0ijqemZ4pJTnAHdnGBpTJApTRqgxDMa5eALHTpLdnv9usoGhw9IZlwB1fMcak3NLEJbUNpwHMn2Tpt6fs5+oxiEyIFyKXWGhR8x0hjgBBQedSejSuNjemA+HRcB0c0L6cJc4QKyQoVGBTBgxgAhuQYAxYABbDJZBQwKmIGAyEDODmmCAgGTmKkAGz4wCAA) what you need? Not sure, TBH

Comment: @VRoxa - very close ? but how can I use it with class declaration ?

Answer (score 0):

```
interface MyInterface {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
  nestedObj: Omit<MyInterface, 'nestedObj'>
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
  nestedObj: {
    prop1: string; // Ok as MyClass has prop1 property. If this would be missing then it would be an error.
    prop2: number; // Ok as MyClass has prop2 property. If this would be missing then it would be an error.
    prop3: number; // This is still OK because inheriting class or interface has to have the properties of the thing it inherits but it can always have more properties and you can't limit that
  }
}

const x: MyInterface = new MyClass();
x.prop1 // OK
x.prop2 // OK
x.prop3 // Fail as you've strictly defined x as MyInterface not MyClass
```

More about this topic here [Generic type with strict shape constraint in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51496335/generic-type-with-strict-shape-constraint-in-typescript)

Comment: Is there a way to forbid prop3 declaration in nestedObj  ?